# C# Create a general method parameter

Tags: c#, types, parameters

I have program with 2 classes and i'm trying to create a method, which formats some `System.Windows.Forms` objects of the other class.

This is my code:

```
    internal void Format(Panel component, int width, int height, int x, int y)
    {
        component.Width = width;
        component.Height = height;
        component.Left = x;
        component.Top = y;
    }

    internal void Format(GroupBox component, int width, int height, int x, int y)
    {
        component.Width = width;
        component.Height = height;
        component.Left = x;
        component.Top = y;
    }

    internal void Format(Button component, int width, int height, int x, int y)
    {
        component.Width = width;
        component.Height = height;
        component.Left = x;
        component.Top = y;
    }
```

I can create the same methods (with different object parameter) for all required object types, but maybe **there is a way to create it with just one method with 'general/overall/common' parameter for all object types**.

Comment: They all inherit from the `Control` class, you could use this base class instead, I would recommend a check and either throwing a exception if the  object is not one of the ones you support or return false or something.

Comment: It works! And also thanks for the advice, i will!

Comment: No problems. As @Ephraim posted an answer about it, id recommend marking that as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Control` as your parameter data type since all controls inherit from this class.

```
internal void Format(Control component, int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
    component.Width = width;
    component.Height = height;
    component.Left = x;
    component.Top = y;
}
```